# "bad operand types for binary operator" and "incomparable types: char and Random" errors

Tags: java

This program is supposed to be a guessing game in which you input a letter between  a and j and try to guess the randomly chosen answer.
I keep getting error messages regarding my if statements.
For the ones with < or >, it says "error: bad operand types for binary operator".
For the ones with == or !=, it says error: incomparable types: char and Random.
What can I do to fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

class Guess{

    public static void main( String[] args ){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter in the range a to j. You have three guesses. ");

    System.out.print("Enter your first guess: ");

    Random r = new Random();
    char i = (char)(r.nextInt(10) + 'a');

    if(i>r){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high. ");

    } else if(i<r){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low. ");

    } else if(i==r){
        System.out.println("You win! ");

    }

    System.out.print("Enter your second guess: ");

    i = (char)(r.nextInt(10) + 'a');

    if(i>r){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high. ");

    } else if(i<r){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low. ");

    } else if(i==r){
        System.out.println("You win! ");

        }

    System.out.print("Enter your third guess: ");

    i = (char)(r.nextInt(10) + 'a');

    if(i>r){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high. ");

    } else if(i<r){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low. ");

    } else if(i==r){
        System.out.println("You win! ");

        }

    if(i!=r){
        System.out.println("You lose. The letter was " +r+ ".");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking a char is greater than a random object. Not possible and java won't allow you.

Comment: any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Comment: make user enter a character and then compare it with 'i'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is a primitive type and `Random` is a reference type. You can't compare them freely using the <, >, == or != operators.

From what I see in your code, you never actually get an input from the user. You should use the scanner to read from the standard input and compare the read value with `i`.